# скрипт для скачивания композиций с сайта tidido.com

Tags: javascript, парсер

Господа эксперты, возможно ли реализовать скрипт который будет скачивать композиции из плейлиста на сайте http://tidido.com/

Конкретно сейчас две проблемы:

1. Эмулировать нажатие кнопки play. 1 на рисунке
2. Получить ссылку и скачать файл. 2 на рисунке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

реально это вообще реализовать?

Comment: точно не на js, скорее на php curl и тому подобное.

Comment: можно и на js конечно, используя распознавание образов. Но возни много, и малозаконно.